# Backbone.js TypeError thrown on model.save

Tags: backbone.js

In my current Backbone app, I have no problems creating or destroying 
models. The changes propagate to my server without any problems. But 
whenever I try to do a model.save(attributes), I see a TypeError 
thrown at this line: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L117

The model is updated on the (Rails) server, but something breaks 
afterward. Here's the stack trace. (Sorry, line numbers refer to 
concatenated JS files.)

```
Backbone.Events.trigger() at application.js:11574 
_.extend._onModelEvent() at application.js:12092 
d() at (internal script):1426Backbone.Events.trigger() at 
application.js:11574 
_.extend.change() at application.js:11808 
_.extend.set() at application.js:11680 
_.extend.save() at application.js:11753 
Map.mapMoveGeoPointMode() at app.js:741 
(anonymous function)() at app.js:894 
jQuery.event.handle() at application.js:2966 
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle() at application.js:2600
```

In previous applications, I've had no little problems on saving models 
like this. Any suggestions for what to look at?

Note: I don't think I'm repeating [this fellow's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091630/backbone-js-model-save-returns-typeerror) of trying to save a model with no URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the model is updated properly on the server, I don't think this has anything to do with the `save()` function itself, but rather with the `change` event it's triggering - I think you could test this simply by calling `myModel.trigger('change')` and seeing if that throws the same error.

My best guess as to why this is happening is that somewhere along the way you're binding something other than a function - e.g. an undefined variable - to the `change` event. I'd look for an error like this:

```
myModel.bind('change', this.misspelledMethod, this);
```

but it's pretty much impossible to debug further without seeing actual code, not just a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging advice. You're right, I found a binding where I had referred to functionName() rather than functionName.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are binding to an event on the model and passing in something that isn't a valid function.  Make sure all of your bind statements pass in functions:

```
var FUNC = function() {};
MyModel.bind('reset' FUNC);
```

Comment: Thank you as well for the quick response!